# RegEx: Add punctuation inside a vairable expression

Tags: regex

([:space:])?

Part of my expression allows for the possibility of a direction modifier which can in fact be a combination of up to two (e.g NW). There can also be cases however with a period e.g N.W.

I'm trying to add an optional punctuation to the mix but it isn't working:

```
([[:space:]](N|S|E|W|)([[:punct:]])?{1,2))?
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
\s(?:[NS]\.?[EW]|[NSEW])\b
```

Answer (score 0):

With lots of redundant stuff removed, this would be

```
(\s[NSEW](\.?[NSEW])?)
```

which will match " N", " NW", and " N.W" (but alas also " NS" -- this could be avoided with a more complicated regex or handled in code).

Answer (score -1):

Ok figured it out if anyone interested:

```
([[:space:]]((N|S|E|W)([[:punct:]])?){1,2})?
```

Comment: This will allow `N.N` or `EW`

Comment: Hi thanks, that is fine though in this case as the rest of the regex will make that combination highly unlikely.